# kibana problems on plotting a single value without metrics

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hi all I've a issue problem on visualizing a single value on timestamp. Let me to make an example in order to help you to detect the real problem. I would like to visualize the value, that could be a metric like ANGLE value or price of an item how is move in time but, I'm interested on visualize the average or sum value but only time as x axis and at y axis the real value. I manage to create a dashboard with values and timestamp but the value are aggregated using different metrics like average, count document or sum. Can somone is able to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way in Kibana to visualize "every record" when dealing with even moderately large datasets. If you need to graph every data point, you'll need a different tool.

That said, here's a couple of ideas about how you can get Kibana to describe your data better.

### Use multiple metrics

Almost all visualizations in Kibana support multiple metrics. You could show some combination of:

- Average
- Min
- Max
- Percentiles
- Standard Deviation

### Use top_hits to show a single actual value

The [Top Hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation returns actual values. If you limit the `size` to 1, you can graph on it. While you could argue that this applies to `min` and `max`, with top_hits you have more flexibility about the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a methodology in order to solve the issue, below I post the link. The idea is to plot through jupyter the chart and display them in kibana. It's quite simple but we're not able to control an online monitoring as kibana suggested. (for example modifying query there's no way to analyzing data, but the ALTAIR library let you make some operation like selection /zoom or things like that)
[Link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-jupyter-notebook-visualizations-kibana-dashboards-vega-data-science)